# Checking if Javascript .split() fails

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following function:

```
var checkCode=function(codeString){
  var ifs=codeString.split("if");
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to check if the code fails, as in does not find any `if` strings to split from in the `codeString` that is input to the function?

Comment: If `if` is not contained the length of `ifs` will be 1

Answer (score 10):

If the length of the result is 1, then the split didn't split.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to think of a rhyme to go with this answer.

Comment: If the length of the split is 1, then the split was never done @Pointy.

Comment: If the result's length is one, the split is undone.  – @ZachBrantmeier

Answer (score 8):

It looks like all you want is to check if the function splits and return a boolean state of that action. If so, here's a simple checker:

```
var canSplit = function(str, token){
    return (str || '').split(token).length > 1;         
}
```

and use as follows:

```
canSplit('test if this works', 'if'); // returns true

canSplit('test that this fails', 'if'); // returns false
```

Comment: In this case, instead of splitting the string, you could also use `indexOf` instead, which might be a tad faster.

Comment: @FelixKling, agreed! wanted to stay in context, since this case is around .split(). performance would be a different topic but I agree indexOf is way faster.

Answer (score 5):

It will return an array with the whole string as the only entry.

```
if(codeString === ifs[0]) //nothing was split
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var checkCode=function(codeString){
      var ifs = codeString.split("if");
         if(ifs.length == 1){ alert('no split'); } 
         else{ alert('splitted'); }
         return ifs;
    }
var str = "dfsdfif";
checkCode(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `includes` method of `String.prototype`. Just like below example.

```
var your_var = codeString.includes("if");//return true or false
```

It returns `true` if a string contains specified character else returns `false`. According to `true` or `false`, you can take the decision if you want to `split` string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but it may help someone.

I would use a try catch

```
let ifs: string;
try {
  ifs = codeString.split("if");
} catch {
  // the code fails
}
```

And inside a function

```
var checkCode = function(codeString): string{
  try {
    return codeString.split("if");
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **ES6** destructuring:

```
  const canSplit = (input = '', delimiter) => {
    const [, second] = input.split(delimiter) || ''
    return second !== undefined
  }
```

At first I wanted to use just `return !!second` but then `canSplit("abc-", '-')` would return false.